# HTTPS issue with AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We have setup an ELB with SSL wildcard certificate uploaded to the ELB . The ELB has been setup for tableau server. We have kept 80 and 443 as listener port and have setup rule on ELB for 443 to target server listening on port 80. The http on ELB DNS is working fine but HTTPS is not working at all.
Do we need to setup an A record for the ELB as the certificate is issued against the domain name. Is that all required or are we missing anything else!?

Comment: Yes, that should be all. It does not work?

Comment: Hi Marcin, Let me check and get back . Thanks for the response.